# Dynamic reference in vlookup

Tags: match, excel-2007, vlookup

I have a formula like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A14,Cars!C25:S49,17,0)
```

I would like to know if the below is possible:

The numbers 25, 49 which are specified in the Range of the above vlookup were present in different cells. I.e.,

```
C3 = MATCH(.....) --> Match results in the number 25
C4 = MATCH(.....) --> Match results in the number 49
```

I tried something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A14,Cars!C&C3:S&C4,17,0)
```

But this shows the error. Can someone suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the volatile Indirect() can be achieved with Index along the lines of

```
=vlookup(A14,Index($C:$C,$C$3):Index($S:$S,$C$4),17,false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the function `INDIRECT`. In your case,

```
=VLOOKUP(A14,INDIRECT("Cars!C"&C3&":S"&C4),17,0)
```